# Eu tenho que entrega essa pergunta e eu já tentei e não consegui responder. Sobre Vetor

Tags: visualg

2. Crie um vetor de 10 posições e digite números inteiros aleatoriamente. Depois digite um número e caso ele esteja no vetor, guarde a posição dele para mostrar ao final do programa. Senão mostre a mensagem ao final do programa “NÚMERO NÃO ENCONTRADO”.

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca o que voce tentou até agora

Answer (score 2):

Se eu ainda me lembro algo de visualg é assim

```
    algoritmo
    var 
numerodesejado : inteiro
posicaodesejada : inteiro
i: inteiro
    numeros: vetor[1..10] de inteiro
    inicio
    posicaodesejada <- 0
    numerodesejado <-10
    vetor[1] <-5
    vetor[2] <-10
    vetor[3] <-15
    vetor[4] <- 20
    vetor[5] <- 25
    vetor[6] <-30
    vetor[7] <-35
    vetor[8] <-40
    vetor[9] <-45
    vetor[10] <-50
      para i de 1 ate 10  faca
        se vetor[i]= numerodesejado entao
         posicaodesejada <- i

        fimse
      fimpara
    se posicaodesejada > 0 entao
    escreval ("A posição desejada é ", posicaodesejada)
    senao
    escreval ("POSICAO NÃO ENCONTRADA!")
    fimse

    fimalgoritmo
```